# prevent function interposing in the library that is linked to the library which does the interposing

Tags: macos, linker, clang, dyld-insert-libraries

Well I couldn't find very nice short phrase for my question title, but here is what I mean:

I have a library that interposes some syscalls like `open(2)`.
I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696940/function-interposing-on-osx-mavericks) method for interposing. I add it to `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` in order to achieve my goal.

The library that contains the interposing code is `a.dylib`.

I need to link a library `b.dylib` to `a.dylib` because it contains some functions that `a.dylib` needs.

The issue is `a.dylib` interposes functions in `b.dylib` too which I don't want.

I am not an expert with linking. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour and what's the reason behind this happening?

## UPDATE:

This is how `b.dylib` is built:

```
clang -dynamiclib -fPIC -Wextra -Wall -pedantic -Wl,-single_module <object files> -o b.dylib -install_name <path>
```

This is how `a.dylib` is built:

```
clang -dynamiclib -fPIC -Wextra -Wall -pedantic -Wl,-single_module <object files> -o a.dylib -install_name <path> b.dylib
```

Only `a.dylib` is added to the end of `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: How are you linking `a.dylib` and `b.dylib` together? Show the compile commands; the example you show has only one `dylib` linking to an executable.

Comment: @l'L'l, updated. I should have added that from before. If any more info needed, please ask. Thanks.

Comment: Could you also show `<object files>` and `-install_name <path>`, it's unclear what you have there. It seems more an issue of how you are using `-install_name`, rather you are injecting `a.dylib` into `b.dylib`.

Comment: @l'L'l, path is just installaion location of the library which is different for both. Like I install `a.dylib` to a location `/path/to/alib` and similarly `b.dylib` to some other location. Object files are just `.o` files which are different for both. I am not getting it. Are those concerned with the question? Can you help me understand?

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure library paths are correctly set and linked. Otherwise how would have the call in b.dylib got intercepted? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you want the opposite (eg. `-o b.dylib -install_name <path> a.dylib`)

Comment: I think that would mean linking `a.dylib` to `b.dylib`. But I want to link b.dylb to a.dylib because a.dylib needs b.dylib and not vice-versa.

Comment: It’s still unclear what you’re actually doing. What are you interposing ( a or b ) and do they link to something else?

Comment: a.dylib interposes `open` and a.dylib depends on, say, `processFile` in b.dylib and you want `processFile` to call the `open` defined in the C library and not have its `open` interposed. Have I got that right? If so, should every execution of `processFile` not have its open interposed? Can b.dylib be loaded without a.dylib?

Comment: @JeffHolt , right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say `a.dylib` depends on `b.dylib` but `b.dylib` does not depend on `a.dylib` and that you want no calls in `b.dylib` to ever be interposed. You gave `open` as an example of an interposed function.

The example I gave was that `a.dylib` needs to call `processFile` that is defined in `b.dylib` and it opens files. You don't want the `open` call in `b.dylib` to be interposed ever (whether `a.dylib` is loaded or not).

The only way I know to pull this off is for `processFile` to dynamically load the C library instead of letting `ld` do it automatically.

There are two problems with this approach. The first is that each function that needs to call `open` will need one additional `if` statement to execute the code to resolve the symbol.

The other is that you need to know ahead of time the filename of the C library to load. And if there's a problem resolving the symbol, then you have to deal with a situation that most programs don't have to deal with; at least at a later time.

The code will look something like this:

```
void processFile (char * filename) {
    FILE *fp;
    // c_open can have file scope if thread safety isn't needed
    static int (*c_open)() = NULL;

    if (c_open == NULL) {
        // factor this if more than one function needs open
        void *dlh = dlopen(C_LIBRARY_FILENAME, RTLD_LAZY);
        if (dlh == NULL) {
           perror("cannot load C library");
           exit(1);
        }
        c_open = dlsym(dlh, "open");
        if (c_open == NULL) {
           perror("cannot resolve open in the C library");
           exit(1);
        }
    }
    c_open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    ...
}
```

---

UPDATE

If you do not specify the full pathname to the C library, `dlopen` could open an unexpected file.

Comment: Probably not the answer I actually expected. Never thought it this way. But this _does_ solve the problem. Thanks for the answer and I really like the idea.

Comment: It looked like you wanted something special that `ld` would do when it loads `b.dylib`; like a feature declared when `b.dylib` was written that informs `ld` "to not resolve a symbol to any library other than the one used at the time `b.dylib` was written". I don't believe any such feature exists.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for. But if such a feature doesn't exist, your answer would probably be the best fit-in.